# How to make SQL query from many tables on Rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, inner-join

Thank you for read my quetsion.

I want to know which is the *best* or *correct* way to express queries in Rails which make many joins and select attributes from multiple tables:

```
SELECT 
    ffca.name, 
    ffc.name, 
    ft.title, 
    concat(s.first_name, ' ', s.last_name), 
    pf.name, 
    ft.amount, 
    date_format(ft.created_at,'%d/%m/%y') 
FROM 
    finance_transactions ft 
    INNER JOIN students s                  ON ft.student_id = s.id 
    INNER JOIN payment_forms pf            ON ft.payment_form_id = pf.id 
    INNER JOIN finance_fees ff             ON ft.finance_fees_id = ff.id 
    INNER JOIN finance_fee_collections ffc ON ff.fee_collection_id = ffc.id 
    INNER JOIN finance_fee_categories ffca ON ffc.fee_category_id = ffca.id;
```

If you need extra info, please feel free to ask me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Query as stated above looks plenty correct to me, so what exactly is the problem that you want to have fixed in the above query. And where does the ruby part come in, because all I see is pretty looking MySQL. Or are you asking how to express the above MySQL query in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g

your model is finance_transactions

```
   finace_transaction = FinanceTransaction.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT 
        ffca.name as name, 
        ffc.name as name1, 
        ft.title as title, 
        concat(s.first_name, ' ', s.last_name) as full_name, 
        pf.name as pf_name, 
        ft.amount as count, 
        date_format(ft.created_at,'%d/%m/%y') as time
    FROM 
        finance_transactions ft 
        INNER JOIN students s                  ON ft.student_id = s.id 
        INNER JOIN payment_forms pf            ON ft.payment_form_id = pf.id 
        INNER JOIN finance_fees ff             ON ft.finance_fees_id = ff.id 
        INNER JOIN finance_fee_collections ffc ON ff.fee_collection_id = ffc.id 
        INNER JOIN finance_fee_categories ffca ON ffc.fee_category_id = ffca.id"
    )
```

the table finance_transactions table must have column name, name1,title, full_name,pf_name, count, time

and then you can use:

```
finace_transaction.name1 gets ffc.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to provide a method in your model class as a wrapper

```
class FinanceTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
[...]
  def self.find_fee_transactions
    self.find_by_sql(<<-SQL)
      SELECT 
        ffca.name as name, 
        ffc.name as name1, 
        ft.title as title, 
        concat(s.first_name, ' ', s.last_name) as full_name, 
        pf.name as pf_name, 
        ft.amount as count, 
        date_format(ft.created_at,'%d/%m/%y') as time
      FROM 
        finance_transactions ft 
        INNER JOIN students s                  ON ft.student_id = s.id 
        INNER JOIN payment_forms pf            ON ft.payment_form_id = pf.id 
        INNER JOIN finance_fees ff             ON ft.finance_fees_id = ff.id 
        INNER JOIN finance_fee_collections ffc ON ff.fee_collection_id = ffc.id 
        INNER JOIN finance_fee_categories ffca ON ffc.fee_category_id = ffca.id"
      )
    SQL
  end
end
```